# QProcess CLI Command - 'Bad parameter' when specifying output save location

Tags: python, pyqt5, qprocess

I am using QProcess to run a typical cli command such as 'ping' or 'netstat'. I would like it to run continuously until I tell it to stop. I've provided a cut down version of my code below that uses the "ping" command. If I run the command "ping -t 192.168.0.1 > test.txt" from a cmd prompt it works fine, but when I try to run this in my program below, it produces the error "Bad parameter > test.txt."

It appears that saving the output of cli commands does not count as a recognized argument/parameter for QProcess (the rest of the code works fine as far as I can tell).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
import psutil

## Define origin path.
scriptpath = os.path.realpath(__file__)
scriptpath = scriptpath.replace(os.path.basename(__file__), "")
os.chdir(scriptpath)
origin = os.getcwd()

## Establish UI and interactions.
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # event actions
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        process_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("process")
        process_btn.clicked.connect(self.process)

        end_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("end")
        end_btn.clicked.connect(self.end)

        lay.addWidget(process_btn)
        lay.addWidget(end_btn)

        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._pid = -1

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def process(self):
        program = 'ping'
        arguments = ['-t', '192.168.0.1', '> test.txt'] # Ping 10 times to the router address and save output.
        self.process.setProgram(program)
        self.process.setArguments(arguments)
        ok, pid = self.process.startDetached()
        if ok:
            self._pid = pid

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def end(self):
        if self._pid > 0:
            p = psutil.Process(self._pid)
            p.terminate()
            self._pid = -1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there a way to save the output of cli commands run through QProcess to a text file?

Note: I have tried to implement the same feature with `subprocess.call('ping -t 192.168.0.1 > test.txt', shell=True)` but then I ran into issues with being able to stop the ping. The only way I could stop it was to use the `exit` command in the cli from where my PyQt5 program was run (closing the app just left the text file continuing to update), which isn't ideal for a program with a GUI. If anyone has a solution to this then perhaps I could go back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QProcess` `setStandardOutputFile` method to save process's result into a file.

Comment: I figured there must have been a simple solution. Adding the line:
`self.process.setStandardOutputFile(os.path.join(origin, 'test.txt'))`

before calling the process works like a charm.

It does result in an output that excludes the normal stats that the "ping" command would normally print out when the command is stopped with "exit" or "ctrl-C" (max ping, average, number of packets etc). I don't need these stats but does this indicate it hasn't properly stopped? Is this an issue?

Comment: I can't understand your means, The `QProcess` work like in command line, the message you get is normal , you can filter message.

Comment: It's not a big deal, I think it is working exactly as I need it to, I was just wondering why when I input `"ping -t 192.168.0.1"` into the command line and then press Ctrl+C it ouputs: 
Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:                                                                                            Packets: Sent = 5, Received = 5, Lost = 0 (0% loss),                                                                Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:                                                                              Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 8ms, Average = 2ms

Comment: However, when I terminate the QProcess it simply stops on the last packet it sent and doesn't show stats like in the command line. Like I said earlier, I don't need the stats, I was just worried that the process wasn't completely finished and that it was just 'paused'.

Anyway, I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Oliblish maybe you  need to send ctrl+c char to QProgress that will show statistics info, but i had never try do this.terminate the Qprocess just stop it and is differ send ctrl+c char.